# event delegation in Hammer JS multi-tocuh events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js, event-delegation

I'm trying to delegate the multi-touch gesture events in hammer.js with jQuery's `.on()`, but that doesn't seem to be working.

This works:

```
var main = $('.settings');
var hammerSwipeDown = Hammer(main, {prevent_default: true}).on('swipedown', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("swipe down");
});
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var main = $('#main');
var hammerSwipeDown = Hammer(main, {prevent_default: true}).on('swipedown', '.settings', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("swipe down");
});
```

How can I get the multi-touch gesture events to delegate with the jQuery version of Hammer.js?

Answer (score 0):

For that you should use the [jQuery Hammer Plugin](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js).